# In Rails 5, how do I write a finder "like" query on a member field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, sql-like, finder

I'm using Rails 5.  How do I have this model ...

class Book < ApplicationRecord

```
has_one :author
```

The author class has an attribute "name".  How do I write a query for book objects whose author contains the string "Joe"?  I tried this

```
Book.includes(:author).where(:author => [ "LOWER(name) LIKE :search", :search[Dch => "%joe%"])
```

but no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
Book.joins(:author).where('LOWER(authors.name) LIKE ?', '%joe%')
```

The `plural_table_name.column_name LIKE ...` syntax should work.

You can't use hash parameters to call `where` in this case, since you're using the `LIKE` operator for your query.

Notice I've changed your `includes` to `joins` since I don't know if you're going to invoke the "child" columns once having the result of your query. `joins` is enough to add an `INNER JOIN` clause and gain access to the author columns.